# In next.js what is the point of multi-zoning

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

What is the point of multi-zoning when you can technically create one folder for all the components and link them together?

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation:

With multi zones support, you can merge both these apps into a single one. Which allows your customers to browse it using a single URL. But you can develop and deploy both apps independently.

This is exactly the same concept as microservices, but for frontend apps.